# Prevent cursor "Loading" state when executing new process

Tags: windows, winapi, cursor

I use some framework which sometimes executes new processes. When it happens cursor for small time (1-2 sec) changes to "Loading" state globally (The same behavior will be if you doubleclick any application icon from desktop). In my case it is bad behavior: for example user works in some other programm and cursor somtimes blinks.

When I run my programm from IDE, cursor never blinks globally, so I think that if IDE can do such exec, I can too, by writing some wrapper-executor for my process (without digging into framework and recompiling it), but how, what function for process executing I need, and what flags need to be used?

Comment: There's an option for that in the STARTUPINFO you pass to CreateProcess().  You can turn on STARTF_FORCEOFFFEEDBACK in its dwFlags member.

Comment: It seems working for directly created process, but not for processes which executed by directly created process.